# Password_reset_email template rendering issue

Tags: python, django, rendering

I'm overriding the password_reset_email template.
I"m getting an email with the new template with the parameter rendering.
My problem is that the html tags are not rendered (I"m seeing  and

in the email)

What can cause such an issue?
I'm using Django 1.6

Edit: here's the code:

```
def token_reset(request, is_admin_site=False,
                template_name='two_factor/token_reset_form.html',
                email_template_name='two_factor/token_reset_email.html',
                subject_template_name='two_factor/token_reset_subject.txt',
                password_reset_form=LoginTokenResetForm,
                token_generator=default_token_generator,
                post_reset_redirect=None,
                from_email=None,
                current_app=None,
                extra_context=None):
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('token_reset_done')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    form = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_reset_form(request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            opts = {
                'use_https': request.is_secure(),
                'token_generator': token_generator,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'email_template_name': email_template_name,
                'subject_template_name': subject_template_name,
                'request': request,
            }
            if is_admin_site:
                opts = dict(opts, domain_override=request.get_host())
            form.save(**opts)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

And this is what I get in the email message:

> You're receiving this email because you requested a token reset for your user account at mycompany.com.
>
> ```
> <p>Clicking this link will reset your token:</p>
>
> <p>example.com/signin/reset/token/confirm/MTMyOA-4yy-f567c21e89d469b8af06/</p>
>
> <p>Your username, in case you've forgotten: naama@imycompany.com</p>
>
> <p>We are happy to assist you with any question you might have at support@mycompany.com</p>
> ```

Thank you

Comment: of course, we can help you without your code.

Comment: @BearBrown I've added it, thanks

Comment: What are you expecting and what is being rendered. Please share screenshot and template code via paste service.

Comment: @AnuragRana added thanks